# C Write() Error in Mac

Tags: c

I'm trying to write characters in a text file on my Macbook Air, but it seems not to be working. 
I tried compiling both via Xcode and Terminal.

But the results are same:
File Descripter: 3
write() Error!

Here is the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void Error_handling(char* message);

int main() {
    int fd;

    char buf[] = "Let's go! \n";

    fd = open("data.txt", O_CREAT|O_RDONLY|O_TRUNC);
    if (fd == -1)
        Error_handling("open() Error! \n");

    printf("File Descripter: %d \n", fd);

    if(write(fd, buf, sizeof(buf))==-1)
        Error_handling("write() Error! \n");

    close(fd);

    return 0;
}

void Error_handling(char* message)
{
    fputs(message, stderr);
    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: `O_RDONLY` could be a trace.......

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You open file with `O_RDONLY` and then try to write, of course it reports error.

And as comments suggested the right open variant should be:

```
fd = open("data.txt", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, 0600);
```

Comment: Use `O_WRONLY` instead.

Comment: Also remember when you are using O_CREATE, open() *must* have a 3. argument which is the mode/permissions  of the file.

Answer (score 3):

Your file is opened in read only mode, which naturally prevents you from writing to it.

```
fd = open("data.txt", O_CREAT|O_RDONLY|O_TRUNC);
//                            ^ <- Your problem is here
```

Fix it by using

```
fd = open("data.txt", O_CREAT|O_WRONLY|O_TRUNC, S_IWRITE);
```